# Where is the intrigue meter?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I'm enjoying the Spy system in the game but the 'Intrigue' meter is eluding me! I simply cannot find it! Is it in the Spy menu or is it in the window when I click the city?

Answer (score 5):

When in the spy menu the diamonds by the city name is the city's level of intrigue.

[image]